# need to find data from same field in sql

Tags: sql, qlikview

For table with below data,

```
name      cerification   status
Anuradha       STA  Enrolled
Anuradha       TA   certified
Ravi           TA   certified
Ravi           STA  Enrolled
mandar         TA   certified
sakshi         TA   certified
tushar         TA   certified
```

i need to find no. of people who have enrolled for "STA" and there "TA" status is a must to be certified

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: try to show a table and then people will be able to answer more quickly

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCShA.png @PuneetSinha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is your requirement:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT name)
FROM TABLE
WHERE cerification='TA'
  AND status='certified'
  AND name IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT name
     FROM TABLE
     WHERE cerification='STA'
       AND status='Enrolled');
```

Good luck .... and who so ever down-voted it, this was just an initial answer to make understand it better. Don't judge too quickly.

Comment: yes, but the problem is both the data is in same field

Comment: It doesn't solve his problem. It will return 0 for the example above.

Comment: @Anuradhasingh this should help ... with a sub query

Answer (score 0):

you can use subquery

```
select t1.* from

(
select * from tbale_name where certification='STA'
) t1
  join 
(
select * from tbale_name where certification='TA'
) t2 on t1.name=t2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "FILTER" keyword...

```
select count(name) filter (where cerification='TA' and status='certified'
       and name in (select name from table where cerification='STA' and  status='Enrolled')
from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

As file is tagged as "qlikview" after loading your data into Qlikview you can use set analysis for that:

```
Count(DISTINCT {
           < cerification={'STA'}, status={'Enrolled'} > *
           < cerification={'TA'}, status={'Enrolled'} >
} Anuradha)
```